# Project Management for systems administrator?

Tags: untagged

So one of my goals in 2011 is to get a better grasp of how I do things at my job.  Documentation is one of them and some sort of change management feature when developers and qa engineers request things on the OS level.  I use Redmine for my personal development work and figure it wouldn't hurt to use it for sysadmin tasks. With that said, is anyone doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a great question for this site. As asked, you'll get answers of "yes" and "no." This is more of a discussion, which might be a valid communitywiki question if you asked about different tools/methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people do this! It's a great way to go. You don't need something that is necessarily IT focused but it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some people are doing that.